# HTML button with multiple colors

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to create a button that looks like this using html. I want the button to look like one is on top of the other, not just two rectangles next to each other (so the rounded edges/border-radius is important).

If it helps, I'm looping over a list of documents and displaying them as buttons in this format. It needs to be able to adjust its' width for different document names/extensions. I don't want the .pdf/.docx to be covered if the document name is too long.

[button design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c01DA.png)

I started by creating two buttons and having each on a different z-index, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Is there a way to dynamically size two buttons so that they appear overlapping like this, but are able to adjust their location/width so their text is still visible?

I'm sure this is a simple fix - but I'm stuck

```html
<button style="position: absolute; padding: 10px 20px; background-color: darkgray; border-radius: 15px; border: none; z-index: 1;">Document</button>
<button style="position: absolute; padding: 10px 50px; background-color: gray; border-radius: 15px; border: none; z-index: 0;">.pdf</button>
```

Comment: *"I started by creating two buttons and having each on a different z-index"* - That's how I'd do it.

Comment: The main problem is figuring out the sizes of the buttons. How do I make sure the button on the lower z-index's text is still visible if I don't know how many characters are going to be on the upper button? Then how do I shrink the lower button so the text appears to the right of the upper button and there isn't a bunch of trailing space on the right side.

Comment: Don't bother with two buttons, absolute positioning and z-indices. Just use one button and a span to separate the text. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eomsb02h/5/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Two buttons are going to add to what you need to account for when binding events, and unless each side of the button does something different, it's not worth that additional work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single `button` but wrap the document name in a `span`, then you can apply different styling to the document name and the button itself.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: #555;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

button>span {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">

  <button>
    <span>DocumentName</span> .pdf
  </button>

  <button>
    <span>a-very-long-document-name</span> .docx
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.button{
  background: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.button-document-name{
  background: #666;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 0px 13px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 11px 0px 13px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.button-document-ext{
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">
   <span class="button-document-name">Document Name</span>
   <span class="button-document-ext">.pdf</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything inside 1 element and control the children with display:flex.

```
<style>
    .button{
        display: flex;
        background-color: lightgray;
        border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    .content{
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 3rem;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .secondary{
        background-color: lightgray;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<div class="button">
    <div class="content">
        DocumentName
    </div>
    <div class="content secondary">
        .pdf
    </div>
</div>
```

I try to make this for you, but only the style. You still need the link and href, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pseudo :befor element instead of two buttons

```js
const docs = [
  ["doc1", ".pdf"],
  ["doc2", ".txt"],
  ["doc3", ".csv"],
];

const mydiv = document.querySelector(".root");
docs.forEach((doc) => {
  const docName = document.createTextNode(doc[0]);
  const docExt = document.createTextNode(doc[1]);
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.appendChild(docName);
  btn.classList.add("btn");
  btn.setAttribute("doc-extention", doc[1]);
  mydiv.appendChild(btn);
});
```

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

.btn,
.btn::before {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
}

.btn::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: attr(doc-extention);
  left: calc(100% - 1rem);
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00000050;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want two buttons unless you want a different behavior based on whether a user clicks one side or the other. Many solid ways to do this, here's my approach:

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: gray; 
  border-radius: 15px; 
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
button label, button abbr {
  border-radius: 15px; 
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
button label {
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 20px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
button abbr {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px; 
}
```

```html
<button>
    <label>DocumentName</label>
  <abbr title="Portable Document Format">.pdf</abbr>
</button>
```